# How to remove error from Powershell script and make it return the expected result

Tags: powershell

Hi GUys when I run this script below:

```
$backuplist = Get-ChildItem "E:\res\store\Backup"
ForEach ($dir in $backuplist) {                                                                                                                                                 
$letters= dir $dir.FullName -Recurse
$snd = $letters | Where FullName -like "*SND_BE*" -and $_.name -Like  
   "*Letters*" -and -$_.name l-like "*OvernightLetters*"| where-object  
  {$_.Name -notlike "*MailService*" -and $_.Name -notlike  
  "*CustomerCommunications*"
  -and $_.Name -notlike "*JobQueueResults*" -and $_.name -notlike "*Logs*" 
   -and $_.Name -notlike "*Notifications*" -and $_.name -notlike "*Uploads*"
   -and 
   $_.Name -notlike "*Uploads*"}
   $swy = $letters | Where FullName -like "*SWY_BE*" -and $_.name -Like 

 "*Letters*" -and -$_.name l-like "*OvernightLetters*"| where-object 
 {$_.Name -notlike "*MailService*" -and $_.Name -notlike 
 "*CustomerCommunications*"

 -and $_.Name -notlike "*JobQueueResults*" -and $_.name -notlike "*Logs*" 
  -and $_.Name -notlike "*Notifications*" -and $_.name -notlike "*tUploads*" 
   -and $_.Name -notlike "*Uploads*"}
   $snd | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\SND
   $swy | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\SWY
   }
```

I get this error Copy-Item : Item with specified name E:\Templetters\snd already exist. What can I do differently? And how can I make this script more efficient? Thanks help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (E:\TempLetters\SWY\4:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand I also got this exception message and the script is not returning all the files in the directory that it's suppose to return

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the documentation? If so you would see that the `-Force` parameter will overwrite an existing file. As far as making it more efficient, have a look at [codereview.se].

Comment: CodeReview is not a good place for this code yet as it does not do what the OP expects

Comment: @Matt agreed, I should have been more clear that I meant that for after the issue is resolved and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote a log of it, because you were filtering twice and getting child items twice. However, my revised script will write out what the script is doing, but not actually perform the action. This will ensure that it is doing what you expect it to. If it does what you are expecting it to do you can uncomment out the copy-item commands and run it again.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\res\store\Backup" -Recurse |

    # Filter children using Where-Object
    Where-Object -FilterScript {
        ( $_.Name -match "Letters|OvernightLetters" ) -and 
        ( $_.Name -notmatch "MailService|CustomerCommunications|JobQueueResults|Notifications|Logs|Uploads" )
    } |

        # Foreach of those objects, do something
        ForEach-Object -Process {

            # Use a regex switch to decide what to do with the remainder
            switch -Regex ( $_.FullName ) {
                "*SND_BE*" {
                    Write-Host "Copying `"$($_.FullName)`" to `"E:\TempLetters\SND`""
                    $NewPath = Join-Path -Path "E:\TempLetters\SND" -ChildPath $_.Name
                    if ( Test-Path -Path $NewPath ) {
                        Write-Warning "Path `"$NewPath`" already exists."
                    }
                    # Commenting out line below that actually performs the copy 
                    # $_ | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\SND -Force
                }
                "*SWY_BE*" {
                    Write-Host "Copying `"$($_.FullName)`" to `"E:\TempLetters\SWY`""
                    $NewPath = Join-Path -Path "E:\TempLetters\SWY" -ChildPath $_.Name
                    if ( Test-Path -Path $NewPath ) {
                        Write-Warning "Path `"$NewPath`" already exists."
                    }
                    # Commenting out line below that actually performs the copy 
                    # $_ | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\SWY -Force
                }
            } # Close switch -Regex ( $_.FullName )
        } # Close Foreach-Object
```

Comment: Thanks I ran the edit you provided. The script apparently does not perform any action. Observed the ran for awhile and had to stop it. Looking at some of the issues that might be causing this.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It's hard to dissect a script if you don't have all the information. It just did not seem like the script was cleanly going to do what it was intended to do. Also, if these are large backups you will probably want to look into ROBOCOPY instead of Copy-Item. PowerShell doesn't handle paths over 245 characters due to .NET limitations. You could run into issues copying backups. ROBOCOPY is also way faster.

Comment: The path is less than that. But the backup has lots of pdfs files that are embedded in a folder that it has to go through.

Comment: Still could not spot why the previous script did not run though. Were you able to spot any anomaly?

Comment: No offense, but it just looked like a mishmash of different command. Can you modify your description and write out the requirements and goals of the script?

Comment: We have a back up folder where we archive files everyday for every customer we have. That back up location E:\Shares\store\Backup\eachday(which is the day of the letters were produced)\servername\d$\production\mailfolder\namesofcustomer\customermail\mail.  My aim is so get all the mail that have been archived for two specific customer (SWY and SND)since we started backing up files which is 2014. So that is why I doing a recursive search through the folder to find specif files for that partner in the mail folder only as there are other folders in the back up.

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to explain more. I did it before with a different script but I am not getting the expected result as it's not fine tuned the way I want it, and even after excluding the folders I dont want I am still getting the unwanted files and not all the wanted ones.